# VBA Autofilter not equal to

Tags: excel, vba, filter, basic

```
Sub Macro1()
‘Remove all except validated
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:<>"Validated"

Activesheet.Range("$A$2:$O$99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
 End sub
```

How to replace "not equal than" in VBA? 
<> does not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want your filter criteria to exclude "Validated", then try changing this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:<>"Validated"
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<>Validated"
```

Note that the `=` in `Criteria:=` doesn't have anything to do with your filter criteria. (It relates to VBA and how you provide an argument to a named parameter.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How would it be applied in case the criteria itself is a variable?

Comment: @AntonioSantos, depending on the variable type, you might be able to do something like: `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$5202").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>" & someVariable`. This assumes that there is a variable called `someVariable`. If you need to filter by date, you might need to use `CDbl(someVariable)`, since filtering dates programmatically can be a little awkward if I understand correctly.

Comment: Worked nicely! Thank you!